# Sql server can't select from tables from time to time

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, iis, iis-6

We have Silverlight application that is installed on IIS 6. This application use membership API on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 for login. From time to time logged-in users stops can do any queries to the database, but it's not a connection problem, I think just select statements can't return any rows. 
On login users start receiving a message 'The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1''. And this is because the first query to the server is execution of the procedure dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion, which check the schema version.
The query is executed but it's look like the select in the stored procedure can't return any rows. When I execute this procedure in the management studio it returns a correct value.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Do all of your users have the rights to execute this stored procedure?

I believe that this procedure is run once on startup of the application domain (or possibly on first login). Depending on which user credentials are used for the connection, you may get this error.

This error may persist until the app domain is restarted.

Comment: No, we use the same user every time. The problem it's not just in stored procedure on login but also logged-in users can't execute queries to the server